# extracting year from interval given as variable

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to use the date_part function but I have the interval stored in a variable. How can I make it work? Does it work only if between '' ?

```
date_part('year', INTERVAL age_interval);
```

Thank you

Comment: This code should work, if `age_interval` is declared as an interval.

Comment: Yep, it worked that way. At first I declared it as a record, because in other functions it workes, and then trying with a cast in the function but didn't work.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `INTERVAL <constant>` works only if `<constant>` is a *literal*, i.e. a string in single quotes.

You will have to use a cast, either the standard

```
CAST (age_interval AS interval)
```

or the PostgreSQL abbreviation

```
age_interval::interval
```

Comment: Solved the problem declaring it as interval. Which is quite obvious in the end but I thought that declaring it as a record and then casting it could work anyway, but didn't. Thank you